# How do I clone my old mac to a new one?

Tags: time-machine, restore

I have a MacBook Pro running Lion 10.7.5.  I just got a new mac running Yosemite. I have everything from the old mac backed-up on Time Machine. How do I transfer all my files, apps, email, photos in iPhoto, music, etc., to the new mac? I want to get everything I have on my old mac, plus anything new on the new mac, such as new apps.

Will the old Lion OS get installed on the new mac when I use the migration tool? I do not want that!

Comment: Applications > Utilities > Migration Assistant

Answer (score 2):

If you haven't set up the new machine yet, you can do this by connecting your Time Machine drive before booting. (If the backup is on a Time Capsule, it will search for backups on it.) During the setup of the new machine, you'll be presented with the option of migrating your setup from the Time Machine backup.

If you've already configured the new Mac, use the Migration Assistant (Applications->Utilities) to do the same; or reboot into Recovery Mode to restore from the Time Machine backup. I'd actually do a full system reinstall and migration from the Time Machine backup in Recovery Mode to prevent any issues.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Let me give you some more data. I have not configured the new mac at all, haven't even turned it on. The back up is on a time capsule. But what about the OS? Will the old Lion OS get installed on the new mac when I use the migration tool? I do not want that.

Comment: No, it will retain Yosemite and migrate all your user data (documents, settings and any third-party apps) onto the new machine.

Comment: This really sucks. I had planned to configure my new Mac today, transfer everything from Time Machine, etc. I leave on a trip tomorrow and wanted to take my new Mac. BUT… just found out the hard drive I use for Time Machine has a FireWire connector. I'm missing the obligatory FireWire to Thunderbolt adapter. Is there any other way I can transfer the data from this hard drive to the new mac? Tomorrow is the earliest I can get the adapter and I just won't be able to do it. What if I connect the HD to the old mac… is there a way for the new mac to access the data through WiFi?

Comment: You can do the migration from your old machine if it's on the network with no need for the Time Machine backup being in play. The setup process on the new machine will walk you through the process of connecting both machines across the network for Migration Assistant to work its magic.